# sdl software renderer not working , works in hardware accelerated one

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am using sdl2 and tryed to use their software rendering istead of their hardware rendering. Up to now I was using their hardware rendering and everything displayed great. It is very important for me to have a software rendering.

The big question is Why do software renderer and hardware renderer behave differently ? and how to fix it?

Here is my Problem :

Therefore I used `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer` to creat a renderer which renders to a surface and then I display that surface which is in fact the window surface. (I need a surface for some reason...).

The rendering is then made in a loop :

```
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0XFF, 0XFF, 0X00, 0XFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0X0F, 0X00, 0XF0, 0XFF);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0X0F, 0X00, 0XF0, 0XFF);
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = 0;
    rect.y = 5;
    rect.w = 10;
    rect.h = 2;
    SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &rect);
    std::cout << "begin" << std::endl;

    for (auto& i : zIndexOrder) {
        //Rectangles[i]->get_x();
        Rectangles[i]->updat_move_fnct();
        if (Rectangles[i]->everyframe_fct != NULL)Rectangles[i]->everyframe_fct(Rectangles[i]);
        //Rectangles[i]->index_th = i;
    }
    for (auto u : Underwindows)u->Refresh();

    for (auto& i : zIndexOrder)Rectangles[i]->draw(this);


    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0X0F, 0X00, 0XF0, 0XFF);
    rect.x = 0;
    rect.y = 5;
    rect.w = 5;
    rect.h = 5;
    SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &rect);

    std::cout << "true RENDERER " << gRenderer << std::endl;

    if (SOFTWARE_RENDERING) SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(gWindow);
    else SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
```

The two rectangle drawn here with `SDL_RenderFillRect(f->get_screen_render(), &rect);` draw fine but, in `ectangles[i]->draw(this);` If I make the same call It doesn't work I mean I call

```
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(f->get_screen_render(), 0X0F, 0X00, 0XF0, 0XFF);
            SDL_Rect rect;
            rect.x = 6;
            rect.y = 5;
            rect.w = 10;
            rect.h = 55;
            SDL_RenderFillRect(f->get_screen_render(), &rect);
```

in `ectangles[i]->draw(this);` and the rectangle doesn't draw.

notice that the three rectangles are from different size to see the differences, the clear color is not the same as the draw color, `f->get_screen_render()` gives the same pointer to the renderer as the one in the two other call ,  and this part of the code is execute (I know this thanks to the console), and finally it executes between the two other draw.

Could their be a reason why everything works with the hardware accelerated renderer and not with the software one ?

My code consists of thousands of code line so if some one wants it to help me I can give it to him but i can not put it here.

Thank for help ^^

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if (SOFTWARE_RENDERING) SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(gWindow);
else SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
```

You should *always* call [SDL_RenderPresent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent) whatever the rendering driver.

Comment: Thank you for that answer but it still isn't working (I already tried this)

Comment: You should describe your development environment and take a few time to write a small C program that reproduces the incorrect behaviour. Then it will be much easier to help you.